# Hyperref bug with index entry containing quoted | character

Tags: xetex, hyperref, texlive-2020, makeidx

For this MWE, run with xelatex in TexLive 2020 on Windows 10:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\index{foo} % OK, but without this line, the .idx file is empty
\index{Sibelius!Difference between Sibelius "| First and Sibelius "| Ultimate}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `.idx` file (given below) is wrong. Apparently something has misinterpreted the second `"|` as a `"` character followed by a pagenumber-formatting `|` command.

```
\indexentry{foo|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{Sibelius!Difference between Sibelius "|hyperindexformat{\ First and Sibelius "}}{1}
```

`makeindex` then gives the error message

```
!! Input index error (file = test.idx, line = 2):
   -- Incomplete first argument (premature LFD).
```

(Note: IMHO the decision of a software company to name three versions of an app as "Sibelius", "Sibelius | First" and "Sibelius | Ultimate", using the vertical bar characters and spaces exactly as shown, is moronic, but that's what they have done!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite unfortunate, but on the other hand `|` doesn't necessarily print a bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex
\begin{document}

x % something to make the index entry to be processed

\index{foo} % OK, but without this line, the .idx file is empty
\index{a}\index{b}\index{c}\index{d}
\index{Sibelius!Difference between Sibelius~\textbar~First and Sibelius~\textbar~Ultimate}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the `\sibbar` definition do in this MWE?

Comment: @Marijn A left-over. Thanks for noting it.

Comment: What circumstances would make | *not* print a bar in text mode? I don't want to pollute the whole document with dozens of `\textbar`s even if a few are necessary in index entries

Comment: @alephzero Try `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}|\end{document}`

Comment: @egreg That works fine for me, creating a PDF. But in any case, my "real" document doesn't use the article class or the default CM fonts, so if it is a font or font encoding issue, it's going down a different rabbit hole.